# How to insert date value from jdatechooser to database table

Tags: java, mysql, jdatechooser

```
 private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String G_ID=gIDText.getText();
        String G_Title=(String) titleCombo.getSelectedItem();
        String FName=fNameText.getText();
        String SName=sureNameText.getText();
        String Sex=(String) genderCombo.getSelectedItem();
        String dob=(JTextField)dobDte.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().getText();//error
        int age=Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText());
        String country=contactText.getText();
        String nationality=nationText.getText();
        String ZipCode=zipCodeText.getText();
        String email=mailText.getText();
        String PassportNo=passportText.getText();
        String IssuedDate=(JTextField)issDte.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().getText();//Error
        String ExpiryDate=(JTextField).getDateEditor().getUiComponent().getText();//error
        String PIDNo=pidText.getText();
        int ContactNo=Integer.parseInt(contactText.getText());

        Guest guest=new Guest(G_ID,G_Title,FName,SName,Sex,dob,age,country,nationality,ZipCode,email,PassportNo,IssuedDate,ExpiryDate,PIDNo,ContactNo);
        try {
                boolean isAdded=GuestController.addGuest(guest);
                if (isAdded) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NewGuest.this,"Registered Success !");
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NewGuest.this,"Unable to Register ! !");
            }
    }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NewGuest.this,ex.getMessage());
}
}
```

> (mvc)I have tried to insert date from jdatechooser to mysql database,but its shows error,please help me to fix this and if can please retype the correct code for me

Comment: could you please provide the excepton?

Comment: yes here it is : { Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: javax.swing.JTextField cannot be converted to java.lang.String }

Comment: could you please provide the full Stacktrace?
What is the type of `issDte` ?
Also it seems that there should be an syntax error in line 15 of your code-listing, since `JTextField` has no static method `getDateEditor()`

Answer (score 0):

1 - here to set the date from jDateChooser to string

String dob=""+jDateChooser1.getDate();

2 - to insert the date to database you should set the format first

SimpleDateFormat Date_Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date_Format.format(jDateChooser1.getDate())